# PHP: Want to keep a persistent variable when submitting form and reloading self-processing form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a workout logger using PHP and MySQL.  The way I have it set up currently, the user uses a select to choose a workout template - and that value is POSTed to the form page.  The template name is used to query the database for the names of all the exercises in that template and the number of sets per exercise.  The names and sets are put into parallel arrays.

A function is called which generates the form.  An element for the template name (ex. Full Body Workout), one for the exercise name (ex. Barbell Deadlift), and one for the set number, with a label/input pair for: weight, reps, rest, and notes.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCyn7.png)

The increment for the exercise name variable is a counter in $_SESSION, which gets incremented after each successful database insert.

My question is on the logic aspect.  How can do I go about incrementing the $_SESSION variable without reseting it back to zero?

```
 session_start();
//User
$user   = $_SESSION['email'];
$date   = date("Y-m-d");

//Get this script
$thisScript     = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

//This is the value I want to keep persistent
$_SESSION['nameCount'] = (int)0;
$nameCount = $_SESSION['nameCount'];

//Value from select
$template  = $_POST['mySelect'];
//Set log submit button
$logSubmit  = $_POST['logSubmit'];

//Check if user is signed in    
if ($user) {
   if ($template)  {
    require_once("include/connect2db.inc.php");
    require_once("include/htmlHead.inc");

    //Return query
    $result     = getResult($template); //Returns result of template
    $numRows    = getExerciseNum($result);
    $exerciseArray  = exerciseList($result, $numRows); //Returns set of exercises in template

    //For some reason, $result and $numRows is empty after being passed into $exerciseArray
    //Reinitialize  
    $result     = getResult($template);     //Returns result of template
    $numRows    = getExerciseNum($result);  //numRows
    $setsArray  = getSets($result, $numRows);   //Gets number of sets as array 

    //Reinitialize  
    $result     = getResult($template); //Returns result of template
    $numRows    = getExerciseNum($result);
    $exerciseIDArray = exerciseIDList($result, $numRows);

    //Build form
    buildLog($thisScript, $template, $exerciseArray, $setsArray, $numRows, $date, $nameCount, $exerciseIDArray);

    //Require Footer
    require_once("include/htmlFoot.inc");
    mysql_close();
   } else if (empty($template)){
    //Do something if template is empty    
    require_once("include/connect2db.inc.php");
    require_once("include/htmlHead.inc");

    echo "<p>Seems the template is empty</p>\n";
    echo "<p>Template = $template</p>\n";

    //Require Footer
    require_once("include/htmlFoot.inc");
    mysql_close();
   } //End if ($template)
} else if (!isset($user)) {
    //If user not logged in
    require("include/redirect.php");
}
```

Here are the relevant functions:  Build log builds the form and the insert is with it

```
//Build log form using query result and exercise name increment ($x)
function buildLog($thisScript, $template, $exerciseArray, $setsArray, $numRows, $date, $nameCount, $exerciseIDArray) {

$logSubmit  = $_POST['logSubmit'];

if (!isset($logSubmit)) {
    echo "<form action='$thisScript' method='POST' name='log' id='log'>\n";
    echo "<fieldset>\n";
    echo "<legend>$template</legend>\n";

    echo "<h2>$exerciseArray[$nameCount]</h2>\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='exerciseArray[]' value='$exerciseArray[$nameCount]'/>\n";
    $j = 1;
    //Generate exercise form with loop
    for ($i=0; $i < $setsArray[$i]; $i++) {

        echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<legend>Set $j</legend>\n";
//Use $template in a hidden value to work around issue of value being lost after submitting form
echo <<<BODYDOC
    <label>Weight</label>
    <input type="text" name="weight[]" required /> \n

    <label>Reps</label>
    <input type="number" name="reps[]" required /> \n

    <label>Rest Time</label>
    <input type="number" name="rest[]" required /> \n

    <label>Notes</label>
    <textarea name="notes[]"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="set[]" value='$j' /> 
    <input type="hidden" name='mySelect' value='$template' />

</fieldset>
BODYDOC;
    $j++;
    } //End form for loop
echo "<br /><button type='submit' name='logSubmit'>Submit</button>\n";
echo "</fieldset>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
echo "<p><a href='newday.php'>Back</a></p>\n";

//Increment exerciseNameArray counter so next form dispays next exercise name
} //End if empty submit
if (isset($logSubmit)) {
    //POSTed
    $template   = $_POST['mySelect'];
    $set        = $_POST['set'];
    $weight     = $_POST['weight'];
    $reps       = $_POST['reps'];
    $rest       = $_POST['rest'];
    $notes      = $_POST['notes'];
    $user       = $_SESSION['email'];
    //Increment exercise name counter
    $nameCount++;
    //Update Log
    updateLog($user, $template, $exerciseArray, $set, $weight, $reps, $rest, $notes, $date, $nameCount, $exerciseIDArray);

} //End else if
} //End buildLog($template, $x) function

function updateLog($user, $template, $exerciseArray, $set, $weight, $reps, $rest, $notes, $date, $nameCount, $exerciseIDArray) {

    //Insert data with query
    $numRows = count($exerciseArray);

    //Insert user,exercise name, and date 
        $insert = "INSERT INTO stats_resistance
                   (user, exerciseName, date)
                   VALUES
                   ('$user','$exerciseArray[$nameCount]', '$date')" 
                   or
                   die(mysql_error());

        $result = mysql_query($insert)
        or
        die("<b>Query Failed</b><br>$insert<br>" . mysql_error());

    //Query for stat_ID
        $query = "SELECT statsID
              FROM stats_resistance
              WHERE user = '$user'
              AND exerciseName = '$exerciseArray[$nameCount]'
              AND date = '$date'";

        //Get result
        $result = mysql_query($query)
        or
        die("<b>Query Failed</b><br>$query<br>" . mysql_error());

        $statsID = mysql_fetch_object($result);
        $statsID = $statsID->statsID;
        //echo "statsID = " . $statsID;

    //Insert into resistanceSets with statsID as foreignKey
    //Can insert multiple value sets by including comma after set parentheses
            $insert =   "INSERT INTO resistanceSets
                     (statsID, exerciseID, setID, exerciseName, weight, numReps, rest, notes)
                     VALUES
                     ('$statsID', '$exerciseIDArray[$nameCount]', '$set[0]', '$exerciseArray[$nameCount]', '$weight[0]', '$reps[0]', '$rest[0]', '$notes[0]'),
                     ('$statsID', '$exerciseIDArray[$nameCount]', '$set[1]', '$exerciseArray[$nameCount]', '$weight[1]', '$reps[1]', '$rest[1]', '$notes[1]'),
                     ('$statsID', '$exerciseIDArray[$nameCount]', '$set[2]', '$exerciseArray[$nameCount]', '$weight[2]', '$reps[2]', '$rest[2]', '$notes[2]')";

            $result = mysql_query($insert)
            or
            die("<b>Query Failed</b><br>$insert<br>" . mysql_error());

//buildLog($thisScript, $template, $exerciseArray, $setsArray, $numRows, $date, $nameCount, $exerciseIDArray); 
} //End updateLog()
```

Comment: Test ```isset($_SESSION['nameCount'])```, if true, increment it, if false initialize it.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Okay that incremented it, but after the insert, it shows a blank page.  How would I go about getting back to the form page, a meta="refresh" or header() without having to edit my include files?

Comment: Thank you tadman.  This is a school project on an old school apache server that I don't plan to take live (at least this build).  Preventing injection isn't currently an issue, but I do plan to to use MySQLi or PDO after the server upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple matter of ensuring the variable is set, if it is then increment it like any other variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nameCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['nameCount']++;
}
```

Alternatively, given you've set the value of the session variable to a local variable you can increment this local variable and reassign that value to the session variable. I.e.

```
$nameCount++;
$_SESSION['nameCount'] = $nameCount;
```

Both will have the same result.

Comment: Okay, one small follow up.  Once the insert is complete, it displays a blank page since nothing is set to display after the insert.  Is the only way to reload the script using a meta="refresh" or header() at the end of the insert?If so, that would mean I would have to move around my include files which already include a header.

Comment: I would use header() if you need to reload the page with the new data; I don't really understand what your problem is with the include files.

Comment: Mick Watkins - I currently have it where the html head is generated if the user is signed in and there is a template.  So when the program enters the insert query, there is already a header sent.